# javascript for loop order of execution

Tags: javascript, loops

Can anyone enlighten me about this stuff..
So i'm reading an article about closure from this website https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/

The article states whats happening behind the scene of this regular for loop

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);  // 1 2 3 4
}
```

// From the article

```
1st pass: i is 1, increment to 2, check is 2 < 5? Yes, so output.

2nd pass: i is 2, increment to 3, check is 3 < 5? Yes, so output.

3rd pass: i is 3, increment to 4, check is 4 < 5? Yes, so output.

4th pass: i is 4, increment to 5, check is 5 < 5? No, so exit loop.
```

My question is if `i` was already incremented should 1 no longer be the first output? I am really  confuse now.

Comment: Incrementation occurs at the *end* of an iteration, not the beginning. What you posted has nothing to do with closures.

Comment: First step is initialization then condition check and after that loop body executes and then increment step gets executed.

Comment: @CertainPerformance but the article said it goes with the order of first, third, second order

Comment: Look at [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead.

Comment: It really goes `i is 1; 1st pass: check is 1 < 5? Yes, so output, increment to 2; 2nd pass: check is 2 < 5? Yes, so output, increment to 3;`

Comment: @mplungjan i see maybe that was it... the author didn't make it clear..

Answer (score 1):

Linked explanations are obviously wrong, your loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);  // 1 2 3 4
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
var i=1;
while (i<5) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

So:

1. i = 1
2. test 1<5, log(1) then increment
3. test 2<5, log(2) then increment
4. etc.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR LOOP SYNTAX**

`for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement`

- An **expression** used to *initialize* a counter variable. (*var i=0 in example*)
- The **condition** to be evaluated *before* each *loop iteration*. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. (*i<5 in example*)
- A **final expression** to be evaluated at the *end* of each *loop iteration* (*i++ in example*)
- A **statement** that is executed as long as the condition evaluates to *true*. (*console.log(i) in example*)

**Source**: [**MDN for Loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```js
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```